# How to put values without repeating inside a table

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

I have a problem, I need put different values inside a table and I do not know how to make the structure.
**These are the values in database:**

```
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|  id_r_a_p_f  |  id_param  |  id_frec  |  value1  |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       1      |   Param1   |   Frec1   |   A      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       2      |   Param2   |   Frec1   |   B      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       3      |   Param3   |   Frec1   |   C      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       4      |   Param4   |   Frec1   |   D      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       5      |   Param1   |   Frec2   |   E      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       6      |   Param2   |   Frec2   |   F      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       7      |   Param3   |   Frec2   |   G      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
|       8      |   Param4   |   Frec2   |   H      |
|--------------|------------|-----------|----------|
```

and this is what I want in **my view**

```
|--------------|------------|-----------|
|     Param    |   Frec1    |   Frec2   |
|--------------|------------|-----------|
|     Param1   |   A        |   E       |
|--------------|------------|-----------|
|     Param2   |   B        |   F       |
|--------------|------------|-----------|
|     Param3   |   C        |   G       |
|--------------|------------|-----------|
|     Param4   |   D        |  H        |
|--------------|------------|-----------|
```

Not matter what I do the result is the same, the **param** repeat instaed of be diferent.

I catch de value fron database OK, but I do not know how put in this style in the view. I let you my **view code** if work for anything.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td> Param </td>
             <?php
                  $cont_frec = 0;
                     foreach ($query_frec->result() as $frec) {
             ?>     
         <td>
            <?php echo $frec->frec; ?>
         </td>
             <?php
                $cont_frec++;
             }// end foreach frec
             ?>
      </tr>
<?php
    $previous_frec = '';
      for ($rel = 0; $rel < $cont_eval_x_frec; $rel++) {
         if ($prev_param != $list_eval_x_frec[$rel]['id_param']) {
           ?>
           <tr>
              <td>
                  <?php echo $list_eval_x_frec[$rel]['id_param']; ?>   
              </td>
              <?php
            }
             $previous_frec != $list_eval_x_frec[$rel]['id_frec'];
            ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $list_eval_x_frec[$rel]['value_1']; ?>
            </td>
             <?php
          }// for rel
          ?></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not the most experienced PHP Coder out there but my approach would be to first build an array with your query to something like this:

```
$table_frec = array();
while($row = $query_frec->fetch_assoc()){
  $table_frec[$row['id_param']][$row['id_frec']] = $row['value1']
}
```

This will give you an array that looks like:

```
$table_frec { 
    [Param1]=>{
       [Frec1]=>"A"
       [Frec2]=>"B"
    }
    [Param2]=>{
       [Frec1]=>"C"
       [Frec2]=>"D"
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can build your table using that array.

Comment: I tried what you said but give me `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`

Comment: I am not sure how you're doing your query and I'm assuming mysql is being used. I edited to show how I would typically call my mysql results, with the use of a mysqli object.